# Support Contextual Action Bar never inflates

Tags: android, android-support-library, contextual-action-bar, android-actionbaractivity

In order to add a contextual action bar to my application using the support action bar v7 library I implemented it like this :

My ActionBarActivity (support v7) :

```
    package com.supinfo.cubbyhole.mobileapp.activities;

import com.supinfo.cubbyhole.mobileapp.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Homy extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ActionMode mActionMode;
    private ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // I instantiate and fill my list with custom adapter ... All is fine
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.home_list);

        String[] array = {"test", "test2", "test3"};
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, array));

        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                 if (mActionMode != null) {
                     return false;
                 }
                 mActionMode = startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                 view.setSelected(true);
                 return true;
         }
     });

    } 

    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        // Called each time the action mode is shown. Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
        // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false; // Return false if nothing is done
        }

        // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        // Called when the user exits the action mode
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mActionMode = null;
        }

    };

}
```

My contextual_menu.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/test"
        android:titleCondensed="Delete">
    </item>

</menu>
```

And when I try to long click on an item I got this stack error :

```
06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.initForMode(ActionBarContextView.java:206)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.startActionMode(ActionBarImpl.java:448)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.Activity.onWindowStartingActionMode(Activity.java:4881)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:341)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2256)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.Activity.startActionMode(Activity.java:4864)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.startSupportActionMode(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:185)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.startSupportActionMode(ActionBarActivity.java:194)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.supinfo.cubbyhole.mobileapp.activities.Home$4.onItemLongClick(Home.java:414)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2815)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2765)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     ... 25 more
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.indexOfStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:295)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.access$000(StateListDrawable.java:274)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.onStateChange(StateListDrawable.java:100)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.<init>(StateListDrawable.java:327)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.<init>(StateListDrawable.java:75)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:843)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1950)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:885)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1950)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:885)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1950)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:885)
    06-01 18:11:09.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.graphics.drawable
```

I don't understand why the contextual menu doesn't display...

**-- EDIT --**

Issue was due to the Override of the close icon in my auto generated theme...
I just had to comment this line :

```
<item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Cubbyhole</item>
```

Comment: You've never assigned the list view.

Comment: Man, not all code is written there, just the main for my issue..

Comment: The problem is probably within your adapter because when I try your code with a simple ArrayAdapter<String>, it has no problems.

Comment: Impossible.. I restarted eclipse and my computer and now I have some import issues on extarnal projects library.. eclipse sucks and Android Studio is still in beta... I think it's an Eclipse issue

Comment: I tried with ArrayAdapter<String> and got same error! (restarting eclipse removed the imports bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is an stack overflow (how appropriate) while expanding the "close" icon in the CAB. Probably because of a state-list drawable that references itself.

The relevant code in `ActionBarContextView.java` is:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
mClose = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_mode_close_item, this, false);
```

The problem might be related to an incorrect definition of the `actionModeCloseDrawable` drawable, or the `actionModeCloseButtonStyle` style.

Is either one of them customized in your theme, possibly with an recursive state-list drawable?

In case everything is correctly defined, I would suggest cleaning and rebuilding the project (the resource ids may be incorrect).

Comment: Yes my theme is auto generated using Android Action Bar Style Generator and this line set the value for the closedrawable :  <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/abc_ic_cab_done_holo_dark</item>

Comment: @eento Is abc_ic_cab_done_holo_dark a png file or an xml file?

Comment: It's a png resource, I tried to comment lines with this set and the problem is still there

Comment: @eento ok, it may be the other style (edited my answer) please check `actionModeCloseButtonStyle` too (and the drawables it references).

Comment: actionModeCloseButtonStyle is set by sub themes, and the final theme just set a drawable.. What do you expect I can do ??

Comment: @eento well, the "reasonable" causes seem to be out, sorry :/ have you both refreshed and cleaned the project in eclipse?

Comment: But do you know how can I set a different Drawable for actionModeCloseDrawable ?

Comment: Just find the file that `actionModeCloseDrawable` points to and change it for the one you want.

Comment: ok, but this stack overflow is very strange.. thx for help, I think i will not use this CAB because it doesnt take all the space available in my action bar to display Menus...